# Find all the prime implicants for the following Boolean functions, and determine which are essential.

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, boolean-algebra

Find all the prime implicants for the following Boolean functions, and
determine which are essential:

F(W,X,Y,Z) = Im(0,2,5,7,8,10,12,13,14,15)

Book solution:

Prime = XZ, WX, X'Z', WZ'

Essential = XZ, X'Z'

The following is my attempt at tackling the problem, but my answer is not matching the book's answer.

Could anyone assist ?

[image: Possible solution to the question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering in the Karnaugh Map should be:
\begin{pmatrix}
AB/CD   & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10  \\
00  & 0  & 1 &  3 &  2  \\
01  &  4  & 5 & 7 &  6 \\
11  &  12  &  13  &  15  & 14 \\
10  &  8 &  9  &  11  & 10
\end{pmatrix}
Thus your map should look like this
\begin{pmatrix}
WX/YZ   & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10  \\
00  & 1  & 0 &  0 &  1  \\
01  &  0  & 1 & 1 &  0 \\
11  &  1  &  1  &  1  & 1 \\
10  &  1 &  0  &  0  & 1
\end{pmatrix}
There you can see that XZ is a prime implicant you missed. 
Btw as the matrix is symmetrical you see that Y can be omitted and you could simplify the matrix to
\begin{pmatrix}
WX/Z   & 0 & 1 \\
00  & 1  & 0   \\
01  &  0  & 1  \\
11  &  1  &  1  \\
10  &  1 &  0 \end{pmatrix}